# Got error with rowediting when scrolling

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-cmd

i try to use sencha cmd to create a project. But when using rowediting plugin, i got error

> "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'getAttribute' of undefined or
>   null reference"

whenever i scroll up/down over the editor on the grid.

Could you let me know what wrong here?

[please click here to see more detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NiVt.png)

Here my code look like:

```
Ext.define("Sample.view.common.HelloWorld",{
    extend: "Ext.grid.Panel",
    alias: 'widget.app-helloworld',
    requires: [
        'Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing',
        'PCS.config.Locale'
    ],
    bind: '{hellostore}',
    layout: {type: 'fit', align: 'stretch'},
    initComponent: function() {
        Ext.apply(this, {
            plugins: [{
                ptype: 'rowediting',
                clicksToEdit: 2,
                pluginId: 'helloeditor',
                errorsText: 'Warning',
                listeners: {
                    cancelEdit: 'onCancelEdit',
                    validateedit: 'onValidateEdit',
                    edit: 'onEdit'
                }
            }],
            columns: [
                new Ext.grid.RowNumberer({
                    width: 30,
                    align: 'center'
                }), {
                    header: this.lblSysNm,
                    dataIndex: 'sysCd',
                    width: 150,
                    align: 'center',
                    itemId: 'colSystem',
                    renderer: function(value, metaData){
                        return metaData.record.data.sysNm;
                    },
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'combo',
                        bind: {
                            store: '{systemCodeCombo}' 
                        },
                        displayField: 'optionName',
                        valueField: 'optionValue',
                        allowBlank: false,
                        activeError: 'important',
                        editable: false
                    }
                }, {
                    header: this.lblDept,
                    dataIndex: 'deptCd',
                    width: 180,
                    align: 'center',
                    itemId: 'colDept',
                    renderer: function(value, metaData){
                        return metaData.record.data.deptNm;
                    },
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'combo',
                        bind: {
                            store: '{deptCodeCombo}' 
                        },
                        displayField: 'optionName',
                        valueField: 'optionValue',
                        allowBlank: false,
                        activeError: 'important',
                        editable: false
                    }
                }, {
                    header: this.lblCountryCd,
                    dataIndex: 'cntyCd',
                    width: 120,
                    align: 'center',
                    itemId: 'colCountryCd',
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        maxLength : 2,
                        enforceMaxLength : true,
                        allowBlank: false,
                        activeError: 'important',
                        fieldStyle: 'text-align: center;text-transform:uppercase',
                        readOnly: true,
                        afterRender: function() {
                            this.el.on('click','openCountryPopup');
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    header: this.lblCountryNm,
                    dataIndex: 'cntyNm',
                    width: 170,
                    align: 'left',
                    itemId: 'colCountryNm',
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        maxLength : 50,
                        enforceMaxLength : true,
                        allowBlank: false,
                        activeError: 'important',
                        readOnly: true,
                        afterRender: function() {
                            this.el.on('click','openCountryPopup');
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    header: this.lblReason,
                    dataIndex: 'reason',
                    width: 340,
                    align: 'left',
                    itemId: 'colReason',
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        maxLength : 200,
                        enforceMaxLength : true,
                        allowBlank: false,
                        activeError: 'important'
                    }
                }, {
                    header: this.lblLastUpd,
                    dataIndex: 'updUserId',
                    width: 100,
                    align: 'center',
                    itemId: 'colLastUpd',
                    editable: false
                }, {
                    header: this.lblLastUpdDt,
                    dataIndex: 'updDt',
                    xtype: 'datecolumn',
                    format: 'Y-m-d H:i',
                    width: 150,
                    align: 'left',
                    itemId: 'colLastUpdDt',
                    editable: false
                }
            ]
        });
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

Comment: Which ExtJS version are you even using? Is your plugin even compatible with that version?

Comment: I'm using ExtJS version 5.1.1.366. and I'm using Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing which came along with ExtJS SDK.